# Popup on top of each other VUEJS3

Tags: vue.js, popup, vuejs3, primevue

I want to put several Buttons, each one opening a different Popup. A Popup would print data concerning its Button.

I have a Popup.vue component :

```
<template>
    <div class="popup">
        <div class="popup-inner">
            <slot />
            <Button class="popup-close" @click="TogglePopup()">
                Close
            </Button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ['TogglePopup']
}
</script>
```

And in another .vue I call it like that :

```
    <template>
        <div v-for="infoItem in data" :key="infoItem.name"> // loop to create several buttons
    
           <Button
              icon="pi pi-eye"
              @click="() => TogglePopup('buttonTriggerDetail')">
           </Button>
    
           <Popup
             v-if="popupTriggers.buttonTriggerDetail"
             :TogglePopup="() => TogglePopup('buttonTriggerDetail')"
           >
           {{ infoItem.control }}
           </Popup>
    </div>
    
    </template>

<script>

import ...

export default {
  computed: {
    data() {
      return this.$store.state.data;
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch("getData");
  },

  setup() {
    const popupTriggers = ref({
      buttonTriggerDetail: false
    });
    const TogglePopup = (trigger) => {
      popupTriggers.value[trigger] = !popupTriggers.value[trigger];
    };

    return {
      Popup,
      TogglePopup,
      popupTriggers,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

So it prints several Button but when I click on one, it don't open the Popup with the data of this Button, it always prints the data of the last Button. I think in reality it places all the pop up on top of each others.

How can I do to open only the good Popup with the good data ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake is that you are rendering 3 popups when you need only one with certain props. Think of your popups as of tabs: let popup be rendered by clicking on certain button and pass in props you need, for example:

```
<template>
 <div v-for="infoItem in data" :key="infoItem.name"> // loop to create several buttons
  <Button
   icon="pi pi-eye"
   @click="clickHandler">
  </Button> 
 </div>
 <Popup
   v-if="popupTriggered"
   :TogglePopup="() => TogglePopup('buttonTriggerDetail')"
 >
   {{ data[currentActiveItem].control }}
 </Popup>
</template>

<script>

import ...

export default {
  data () {
    currentActiveItem: 0,
    popupTriggered: false
  },
  methods: {
    clickHandler (index) {
      this.popupTriggered = true
      this.currentActiveItem = index
    }
  }
... // other component data
};
</script>
```

I wrote my example in Vue 2 style because I haven't worked with Composition API yet but I hope you got the idea.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I managed to do something that works fine